# Compiling a blazor project visual studio

Tags: blazor

Today I was surprised how visual studio compiled my project with no errors even though a page uses a custom component that is not included in my solution... So I didn't realize about  this issue until a runtime execution. Is it normal ? or it's a kind of configuration on visual studio ?

I'm trying to realize when components are not rendered because for some reason they have been removed and the compilation time doesn't complain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It compiled because there were no errors in the C# code.

However, you have almost certainly ignored the warnings in the Razor compiler output, and view.

Something like this:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: SO77215097, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\shaun\Documents\GitHub\SO\SO77215097\SO77215097\Pages\Index.razor(11,1,11,39): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'MyMissingComponent'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
1>SO77215097 -> C:\Users\shaun\Documents\GitHub\SO\SO77215097\SO77215097\bin\Debug\net7.0\SO77215097.dll
1>Done building project "SO77215097.csproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 14:46 and took 08.405 seconds ==========
```

[image]

The Razor compiler complained, but didn't error because `MyMissingComponent` may be some sort of special markup handled elsewhere.

The Razor compiler built a valid block of `RenderTreeBuilder` code on that basis.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right with the warnings. Is something I use to forget if the warning list is short!